# Using success/error/finally/catch with Promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-http

I'm using `$http` in AngularJs, and I'm not sure on how to use the returned promise and to handle errors.

I have this code:

```
$http
    .get(url)
    .success(function(data) {
        // Handle data
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        // Handle HTTP error
    })
    .finally(function() {
        // Execute logic independent of success/error
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Catch and handle exceptions from success/error/finally functions
    });
```

Is this a good way to do it, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Promises are an abstraction over statements that allow us to express ourselves synchronously with asynchronous code. They represent a execution of a one time task.

They also provide exception handling, just like normal code, you can return from a promise or you can throw.

What you'd want in synchronous code is:

```
try{
  try{
      var res = $http.getSync("url");
      res = someProcessingOf(res);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log("Got an error!",e);
      throw e; // rethrow to not marked as handled
  }
  // do more stuff with res
} catch (e){
     // handle errors in processing or in error.
}
```

The promisified version is very similar:

```
$http.get("url").
then(someProcessingOf).
catch(function(e){
   console.log("got an error in initial processing",e);
   throw e; // rethrow to not marked as handled, 
            // in $q it's better to `return $q.reject(e)` here
}).then(function(res){
    // do more stuff
}).catch(function(e){
    // handle errors in processing or in error.
});
```

Comment: How would you use `success()`, `error()` and `finally()` combined with `catch()`? Or do I have to use `then(successFunction, errorFunction).catch(exceotionHandling).then(cleanUp);`

Comment: @Joel generally, you do not want to ever use `success` and `error` (prefer `.then` and `.catch` instead, you can (and should) omit the `errorFunction` from the `.then` use a c`catch` like in my code above).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you elaborate why you suggest to avoid `success`/`error`? Also my Eclipse runs amok when it sees the `.catch(`, so I use `["catch"](` for now. How can I tame Eclipse?

Comment: Angular's $http module implementation of the $q library uses .success and .error instead of .then and .catch. However in my tests I could access all properties of the $http promise when using .then and .catch promises. Also see zd333's answer.

Comment: @SirBenBenji $q doesn't have `.success` and `.error`, $http returns a $q promise _with the addition_ of the `success` and `error` handlers - however, these handlers do not chain and should generally be avoided if/when possible. In general - if you have questions it is best to ask them as a new question and not as a comment on an old one.

Comment: This was a direct reply to @Giszmo's question. You orobably missed that ;).

Comment: @SirBenBenji Oh, sorry you are absolutely right - my bad.

Comment: Please add this to your answer: "...the success and error handlers - however, these handlers do not chain and should generally be avoided if/when possible. In general...". It would make the answer more thorough and useful, because the OP asks about `.success` and `.error`. I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33287057/1175496) covers it, but still...

Answer (score 44):

***Forget about using `success` and `error` method.***

Both methods have been deprecated in angular 1.4. Basically, the reason behind the deprecation is that they are not *chainable-friendly*, so to speak.

With the following example, I'll try to demonstrate what I mean about `success` and `error` being not *chainable-friendly*. Suppose we call an API that returns a user object with an address:

*User object:*

```
{name: 'Igor', address: 'San Francisco'}
```

*Call to the API:*

```
$http.get('/user')
    .success(function (user) {
        return user.address;   <---  
    })                            |  // you might expect that 'obj' is equal to the
    .then(function (obj) {   ------  // address of the user, but it is NOT

        console.log(obj); // -> {name: 'Igor', address: 'San Francisco'}
    });
};
```

**What happened?**

Because `success` and `error` return the ***original promise***, i.e. the one returned by `$http.get`, the object passed to the callback of the `then` is the whole *user* object, that is to say the same input to the preceding `success` callback.

If we had chained two `then`, this would have been less confusing:

```
$http.get('/user')
    .then(function (user) {
        return user.address;  
    })
    .then(function (obj) {  
        console.log(obj); // -> 'San Francisco'
    });
};
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `success` and `error` are [only added to the immediate return](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/http.js#L975) of the `$http` call (not the prototype), so if you call another promise method between them (like, you normally call `return $http.get(url)` wrapped in a base library, but later decide to toggle a spinner in the library call with `return $http.get(url).finally(...)`) then you'll no longer have those convenience methods.

Answer (score 40):

I think the previous answers are correct, but here is another example (just a f.y.i, success() and error() are deprecated according to AngularJS [Main page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
$http
    .get('http://someendpoint/maybe/returns/JSON')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ', e);
        throw e;
    }).finally(function() {
        console.log('This finally block');
    });
```

Comment: Finally doesn't return the response, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

What type of granularity are you looking for?  You can typically get by with:

```
$http.get(url).then(
  //success function
  function(results) {
    //do something w/results.data
  },
  //error function
  function(err) {
    //handle error
  }
);
```

I've found that "finally" and "catch" are better off when chaining multiple promises.

Comment: In your example, the error handler only handles $http errors.

Comment: Yes, I still need to handle exceptions in the success/error functions as well. And then I need some kind of common handler (where I can set things like `loading = false`)

Comment: You have a brace instead of a parentheses closing off your then() call.

Comment: This doesnt work on 404 response errors, only works on `.catch()` Method

Comment: This is the correct answer for handling http errors returned to controllers

Answer (score 5):

In Angular $http case, the success() and error() function will have response object been unwrapped, so the callback signature would be like $http(...).success(function(data, status, headers, config))

for then(), you probably will deal with the raw response object. 
such as posted in AngularJS $http API document

```
$http({
        url: $scope.url,
        method: $scope.method,
        cache: $templateCache
    })
    .success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || 'Request failed';
        $scope.status = status;
    });
```

The last .catch(...) will not need unless there is new error throw out in previous promise chain.

Comment: Success/Error methods are deprecated.

Answer (score -3):

I do it like Bradley Braithwaite suggests in his [blog](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/):

```
app
    .factory('searchService', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
        var service = {};

        service.search = function search(query) {
            // We make use of Angular's $q library to create the deferred instance
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http
                .get('http://localhost/v1?=q' + query)
                .success(function(data) {
                    // The promise is resolved once the HTTP call is successful.
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(reason) {
                    // The promise is rejected if there is an error with the HTTP call.
                    deferred.reject(reason);
                });

            // The promise is returned to the caller
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return service;
    }])
    .controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', function($scope, searchService) {
        // The search service returns a promise API
        searchService
            .search($scope.query)
            .then(function(data) {
                // This is set when the promise is resolved.
                $scope.results = data;
            })
            .catch(function(reason) {
                // This is set in the event of an error.
                $scope.error = 'There has been an error: ' + reason;
            });
    }])
```

> Key Points:
>
> - The resolve function links to the .then function in our controller i.e. all is well, so we can keep our promise and resolve it.
> - The reject function links to the .catch function in our controller i.e. something went wrong, so we can’t keep our promise and need to
>     reject it.

It is quite stable and safe and if you have other conditions to reject the promise you can always filter your data in the success function and call `deferred.reject(anotherReason)` with the reason of the rejection.

**As Ryan Vice suggested in the comments**, this may not be seen as useful unless you fiddle a bit with the response, so to speak.

Because `success` and `error` are deprecated since 1.4 maybe it is better to use the regular promise methods `then` and `catch` and transform the response within those methods and return the promise of that transformed response.

I am showing the same example with both approaches and a third in-between approach:

`success` and `error` approach (`success` and `error` return a promise of an HTTP response, so we need the help of `$q` to return a promise of data):

```
function search(query) {
  // We make use of Angular's $q library to create the deferred instance
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('http://localhost/v1?=q' + query)
  .success(function(data,status) {
    // The promise is resolved once the HTTP call is successful.
    deferred.resolve(data);              
  })

  .error(function(reason,status) {
    // The promise is rejected if there is an error with the HTTP call.
    if(reason.error){
      deferred.reject({text:reason.error, status:status});
    }else{
      //if we don't get any answers the proxy/api will probably be down
      deferred.reject({text:'whatever', status:500});
    }
  });

  // The promise is returned to the caller
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

`then` and `catch` approach (this is a bit more difficult to test, because of the throw):

```
function search(query) {

  var promise=$http.get('http://localhost/v1?=q' + query)

  .then(function (response) {
    // The promise is resolved once the HTTP call is successful.
    return response.data;
  },function(reason) {
    // The promise is rejected if there is an error with the HTTP call.
    if(reason.statusText){
      throw reason;
    }else{
      //if we don't get any answers the proxy/api will probably be down
      throw {statusText:'Call error', status:500};
    }

  });

  return promise;
}
```

There is a halfway solution though (this way you can avoid the `throw` and anyway you'll probably need to use `$q` to mock the promise behavior in your tests):

```
function search(query) {
  // We make use of Angular's $q library to create the deferred instance
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('http://localhost/v1?=q' + query)

  .then(function (response) {
    // The promise is resolved once the HTTP call is successful.
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
  },function(reason) {
    // The promise is rejected if there is an error with the HTTP call.
    if(reason.statusText){
      deferred.reject(reason);
    }else{
      //if we don't get any answers the proxy/api will probably be down
      deferred.reject({statusText:'Call error', status:500});
    }

  });

  // The promise is returned to the caller
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Any kind of comments or corrections are welcome.

Comment: Why would you use $q to wrap the promise in a promise. Why not just return the promise that is returned by $http.get()?

Comment: Because `success()` and `error()` wouldn’t return a new promise as `then()` does. With `$q` we make our factory to return a promise of data instead of a promise of an HTTP response.

Comment: you response is confusing to me so maybe i'm not explaining myself well. unless you are manipulating the response then you can simply return the promise that $http returns. see this example i just wrote: http://jsbin.com/belagan/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RyanVice I edited my answer to explain better. I hope now my point is more clear.

Comment: That's a good clarification but checking status for error code is unnecessary as promise will get rejected AFIK

Comment: Good point @RyanVice, it is corrected now. Other than that which option would you prefer?

Comment: You can check my fiddle in the comment above for the pattern I recommend but it's basically

```function search(query) {
  return $http.get('http://localhost/v1?=q' + query)
}```

Comment: Unless you need to do something meaningful with the return there's no value in wrapping a promise in a promise. It'd be like catching and rethrowing an exception without doing anything. There's no value to it.

Comment: Agreed @RyanVice but I need to treat the response in the factory in case the api is down (otherwise status is -1). My goal is to encapsulate all the call logic in the factory so that the controller doesn't have to know anything about it.

Comment: I don't see the value. It feels unnecessary to me and I reject code reviews on my projects that use this approach but if your getting value out of it then you should use it. I've also seen a few promise in angular best practice articles calling out unnecessary wrapping as a smell.

Comment: This is a [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)