# success&error vs. then&catch in AngularJS $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-http

In answer to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559341/using-success-error-finally-catch-with-promises-in-angularjs) was said

> you do not want to ever use success and error (prefer .then and .catch instead

and

> $http returns a $q promise with the addition of the success and error handlers - however, these handlers do not chain and should generally be avoided if/when possible

and that success and error unwraps response object, but you can access status and such anyway so that doesn't seem relevant.

I also found [this blogpost](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http) where author talks about confusion with other frameworks' ajax query commands and something about "You might not always know you're doing AJAX stuff.", which I don't fully understand.

So I'm little fuzzy on the reasoning behind "use then/catch instead of success/error". Is it mainly because of chaining errorcatching? Are the reasons outlined sufficient and I just don't get it? Is success/error fine in some situations? What are the considerations for the choice?

In all AngJS tutorials I've read and even answers here on stackowerflow I only saw success/error IIRC . . .